# TinyMCE and Yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, tinymce

I've successfully installed Yii's extension TinyMCE. However, it's majorly outdated and I want to use the latest version of TinyMCE.

From what I've read I think I have to use Yii's register custom assets, but I'm unsure if I need to create a class that extends cwebapplication, cwebmodule, etc.

I would appreciate some advice on where to get started on this,
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which TinyMCE extension you are talking about but [this one](https://bitbucket.org/z_bodya/yii-tinymce) is reasonably up to date.

There is a 3.5.8 branch and a 4.0.6 branch respectively.

Updating them to the latest version (3.5.10 or 4.0.10) should be as easy as replacing the TinyMCE files in the vendors folder.